# sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: ssh

Using raspberry my root password was nothing hence typing command "sudo su" I got root privileges but now I don't know why it is giving

"sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set"

and also not able to remote Log in using SSH. Using SSH pi@
it is giving
"Connection reset by peer"

Please help me

Comment: When is this message posted? Also, can you post the results of the command: "ls -al /usr/bin/sudo"

Answer (score 0):

When is this message posted? Where are you logged in from? Are you trying to login remotely as root? Also, can you post the results of the command: "ls -al /usr/bin/sudo" Based on the information so far I would give this answer:

Doing "sudo su" does not mean your root password is nothing: it can be anything, and the command would still succeed. It means your current account has the ability to run sudo (which gives it root privileges, and so the command su is executed as if you were root, and so it does not ask for a password)

To see the name of your current account run the command:

```
whoami
```

To change the root password (in fact any password) without knowing the old password:

```
sudo passwd root
```

And so e.g. to change the password of the user pi without knowing the old password:

```
sudo passwd pi
```

Lastly, try to predict the exit of:

```
sudo whoami
```

[Set user bit, or "sticky bit"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) refers to the program running with root permissions, e.g. in my case, sudo has root permissions even if run by a normal user (and so allows said user to change id). In the image, see that the permissions are -rw**s**r-xr-x . The **s** means suid.
[image]

Comment: Logged in from India . at that time when I was running that command i was root user

Comment: :) "where" I meant logged in from a console of that computer, or remotely such as with ssh? (I was not the one to downvote, and usually would leave some comment as to why if i did) btw, I realize now asking from where might not have been smart as your problem is you cant ssh...